# Launch an openstack instance with two NIC

Tags: openstack-neutron

I want to launch a instance with two vNic card . On one vnic i want use for private network and other vNic use for public network, How we can do that in openstack ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to boot the image with twice the ***--nic net-id=*** argument as in the example bellow:

```
nova boot --image cirros-0.3.3-x86_64 --flavor tiny_ram_small_disk --nic net-id=b7ab2080-a71a-44f6-9f66-fde526bb73d3 --nic net-id=120a6fde-7e2d-4856-90ee-5609a5f3035f --security-group default --key-name bob-key CIRROSone
```

here is the result

```
root@columbo:~# nova list
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name      | Status  | Task State | Power State | Networks                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+

| d75ef5b3-060d-4ec0-9ddf-a3685a7f1199 | CIRROSone | ACTIVE  | -          | Running     | SecondVlan=5.5.5.4; SERVER_VLAN_1=10.255.1.16 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```